# Vba msgbox show only once

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to make the msgbox of this code to appear only once? My problem is that if the user inserts data i.e. from row 501 until 510 the message box will appear 9 times, and I want to have it only once. The reason of this is because the code looks in each cell to verify if something is inserted, and then the content is deleted and the msg appears. If it is possible I would like to keep the format of the code below, but only to show the msgbox once. If not, any suggestions would be welcomed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell22 As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cell22 In Target
        If Not Application.Intersect(cell22, Range("a501:z6000")) Is Nothing Then
            If cell22.Value <> "" Then
                cell22.ClearContents
                MsgBox "You cannot insert more than 500 rows", vbInformation, "Important:"
            End If
        End If

        Next cell22

        Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: check another alternative (my answer below) , which runs faster

Comment: Noting the other answers below, also consider logic that moves the intersection check before the loop.

Comment: Also, your logic says, if cell is not empty, then clear it. In other words, your end result is that all cells are empty. You could just set the range and clear in one hit, similar to what Shai mentioned but without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest another way.

The tasks which access the worksheet, such as `ClearContents` takes the longer to process.

So instead of clearing the contents each time inside the loop for a single cell, and repeat it a few hundred times, use `ClrRng` as a `Range` object. Every time the `If` criteria is met, you add it to `ClrRng` using the `Application.Union` function.

Once you finish looping through all your cells, clear the entire cells in `ClrRng` at the same time.

***Code***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell22 As Range, b As Boolean
Dim ClrRng As Range  ' define a range to add all cells that will be cleared

Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each cell22 In Target
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell22, Range("A501:Z6000")) Is Nothing Then
        If cell22.Value <> "" Then
            If Not ClrRng Is Nothing Then
                Set ClrRng = Application.Union(ClrRng, cell22)
            Else
                Set ClrRng = cell22
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next cell22

If Not ClrRng Is Nothing Then ' make sure there is at least 1 cell that passed the If criteria 
    ClrRng.ClearContents ' clear all cell's contents at once
    MsgBox "You cannot insert more than 500 rows", vbInformation, "Important:"
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell22 As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cell22 In Target

        If Not Application.Intersect(cell22, Range("a501:z6000")) Is Nothing Then

            If cell22.Value <> "" Then

                cell22.ClearContents

                GoTo displayMsg

            End If
        End If

    Next cell22
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

displayMsg:

    MsgBox "You cannot insert more than 500 rows", vbInformation, "Important:"
    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only show it once but clear each cell which is non-blank.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell22 As Range, b As Boolean

Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each cell22 In Target
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell22, Range("a501:z6000")) Is Nothing Then
        If cell22.Value <> "" Then
            cell22.ClearContents
            b = True
        End If
    End If
Next cell22

If b Then MsgBox "You cannot insert more than 500 rows", vbInformation, "Important:"

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```